Linear regression: dependent variable is the multiplication of two independent variables
If $y= x_1\times x_2, $ do we have any ways to conduct a linear regression?

Do you mean that Y is related to the interaction?  Or do you mean that it is literally the product of the two variables?  (Some context might help). Is there measurement error? Do you have a sample or the whole population?

Without more context, there is not a lot to say about this, but I will offer the following three observations.
(1) If the relationship you wish to examine is looking at the product as its own stand-alone concept (e.g., area as opposed to the two separate lengths), then you have $z=x_1·x_2$ and you can simply run a regression predicting $y$ from $z$.
(2) If the relationship you wish to examine is regarding an interaction of two distinct variables (e.g., math interest is $x_1$ and test anxiety is $x_2$), then the product captures the interaction.  However, in this case, best practice is to always include the linear terms in the model as well.  Thus, you would predict $y$ from $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_1 · x_2$.
(3) If you truly believe there is only a relationship of the product in some fashion, then (assuming all values are positive), the best approach would be to look at a log transform of the variables.  That is to say, run a regression to predict $\ln(y)$ from both $\ln(x_1 · x_2) = \ln(x_1) + \ln(x_2)$.
